# Getting missing values after uploading CSV to Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, csv, azure-machine-learning-service

[image]I observed that missing values are generated after uploading the CSV to Azure ML studio.

I have re checked with R , Python and Excel just to confirm there are no missing values in my data. And there are none.

The columns are of strings and integer, both are containing missing values after uploading my CSV into Azure ML studio

Comment: Can you share the CSV file?

Comment: I wont be able to share , since its confidential. I however will edit the question to show a prototype of it

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to tell without looking at the data. Though, since it is a string column, my guess is that it may be picking up on something that it thinks marks as being missing. I haven't found any documentation on this, either. Sorry I can't be of more help, but I'll keep researching.

Comment: Thanks @Jon i figured out the problem leading to it. The "text" column consists of sentences in paragraph. So between the 2 sentences , the azure is replacing it with special characters which is leading to missing values.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out @Anagha!